# A SelfHosted WCF Service over Basic HTTP Binding doesn't support more than 1000 concurrent requests

Tags: wcf, scalability, self-hosting

I have self hosted a WCF Service over `BasicHttpBinding` consumed by an `ASMX Client`. I'm simulating a concurrent user load of **1200 users**. The service method takes a string parameter and returns a string. The data exchanged is less than 10KB. The processing time for a request is fixed at 2 seconds by having a Thread.Sleep(2000) statement. Nothing additional. I have removed all the DB Hits / business logic.

The same piece of code runs fine for 1000 concurrent users. I get the following error when I bump up the number to 1200 users.

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at WCF.Throttling.Client.Service.Function2(String param)
```

This exception is often reported on DataContract mismatch and large data exchange. But never when doing a load test. I have browsed enough and have tried most of the options which include,

1. Enabled Trace & Message log on server side. But no errors logged.
2. To overcome Port Exhaustion MaxUserPort is set to 65535, and TcpTimedWaitDelay 30 secs.
3. MaxConcurrent Calls is set to 600, and MaxConcurrentInstances is set to 1200.
4. The Open, Close, Send and Receive Timeouts are set to 10 Minutes.
5. The HTTPWebRequest KeepAlive set to false.

I have not been able to nail down the issue for the past two days.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Self hosting is not recommended by Microsoft, it's just for test, I didn't know about limitation of self host (and never see it) but you can simply make it service host, I think there are some other options in service host which are not in self host, try it, may be your problem solved.

Comment: Message based activation, monitoring are some options which I had read about not part of ServiceHost, which otherwise are part of WAS and IIS based hosting. Other than that I would try to see if there are any specific limitations on Self hosting. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no errors in the service-side WCF logs, I suspect you are hitting some kind of limit in the HTTP.SYS driver layer, leading to requests being turned away before the service application sees them. I think the default limit in the request queue for a particular application may be 1000.

I'm no expert on HTTP.SYS but you may get some insight by running:

```
netsh http show servicestate
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Would run the command you had suggested. I missed to add a point. The same code does work for 2000 user load with no issues when hosted on IIS.

Comment: @Krishnan: so that means IIS configures HTTP.SYS for itself.

Comment: Chris, I'm running the code on an WinXP Professional box and I was not able get the "show service state" netsh command. I think its supported only on Win2003 OS and upwards, that have new KERNEL HTTT.SYS stack. Not sure about this.

Comment: @John, you are correct. IIS does some configuration to HTTP.SYS under the hoods. There are a bunch of HTTP Settings in Registry related to IIS6 (HTTP) that can be tweaked. But none of those settings were even touched when I ran the code on IIS. That makes me wonder from were the WCF HTTPListener is reading its configurations from? My latest discovery being, an "HTTP 503 QueueFull" error logged in the C:\WINDOWS\system32\Logfiles\HTTPERR folder. I have not been able to find out which setting I need to tweak to fix this.

Comment: @Krishnan: I wonder if the IIS hosting environment might not simply be more efficient than yours>?

Comment: @Krishnan: As I understand it, if you have a HTTPERR folder, you have an HTTP.SYS driver and IIS6. I am sure your problem is that HTTP.SYS is configured with a request queue length limit of 1000 for your application - hence the 503 QueueFull errors. I'm not sure how to configure this, but possibly it is stored in the IIS metabase (Application Pool Defaults) and can be configured via IIS Manager.

Comment: @John: Weighing IIS and SelfHost(WCF ServiceHost) side by side, apart from the  Message based activation, health monitoring and process recycling, I haven't come across any one pointing a scalability issue. If I couldn't resolve this, I would have to fall back on IIS hosting.

Comment: @Chris: Yes I have II6 installed on my XP Box. But I haven't hosted my app in IIS. Would give a try configuring the App Pool Defaults that you had pointed out.

Comment: @Chris: Another interesting find is the same HTTERR folder does exist in an XP box that doesn't have IIS 6 Installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar problems on different servers, depending on their CPUs and RAM. You did not mention the server type, how it was upgraded (XP Pro or Server 2003 upgraded to Server 2008), etc. The way I had resolved the issue was through checking the x:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[version]\config\machine.config. Apparently selecting "unlimited" connection through IIS does not mean "unlimited" connections. The number of connections I ran into errored out after 11 requests at the exact same millisecond.

The issue was related to the number of connections coming from the same source. The performance benchmark tool resided on the same PC which has the same IP. The machine.config contains a constraint on the number of connections from the same source.

Comment: I have tried running the Self hosted WCF Service both on Windows Server 2003 and on Windows XP Professional with SP2. The Clients are simulated using VS2010 ULTIMATE evaluation version (200 users per machine * 6), where each client machine is an WinXP Box. With IIS 5.1 on XP Pro there is a limitation on the maximum number of incoming HTTP Connections. Its set at 10. I think the error that you had ran into should have been on an XP Box where the service was hosted on IIS. But in my case its self hosted.